# schließen und Zustandsveränderung

Tags: grammar, verb-usage, verb-choice

Warum wird in dem folgenden Satz nicht „sein“ sondern „haben“ verwendet? Ich dachte, dass es sich um eine Zustandsveränderung handelt.

> Die meisten Lokale in unserer kleinen Stadt haben ja ab Mitternacht geschlossen.

Comment: In diesem Satz ist _geschlossen haben_ nicht das Perfekt von _schließen_; dementsprechend sind Regeln für die Perfektbildung nicht anwendbar. Ich habe gerade keine Zeit für eine richtige Antwort und verweise statt dessen auf den aktuellen Beitrag (zu _geöffnet haben_, ist aber das Gleiche) bei „Fragen Sie Dr. Bopp“: http://canoo.net/blog/2016/02/04/warum-haben-geoeffnet-gehabt-doch-richtig-sein-kann/

Comment: Danke, der von dir empfohlene Artikel war sehr praktisch und hat das Problem verständlich erklärt.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Beides ist richtig im Fall von Geschäften, sowohl geschlossen/geöffnet *sein* als auch *haben*.

1. Das Lokal öffnet/schließt (die Pforten) und *hat* danach geöffnet oder geschlossen. Hier wird nicht der Zustand beschrieben sondern die abgeschlossene "Tätigkeit".
2. Oder das Lokal *wird* geöffnet/geschlossen und *ist* daraufhin geöffnet/geschlossen (worden). Geöffnet bzw. geschlossen sind hier Zustände.
3. Ebenso kann ein Lokal auch offen/auf oder zu sein oder haben.

Comment: Ich empfinde in diesem Kontext „wir haben geöffnet“ nicht als Perfekt.

Answer (score 3):

Man kann den Satz auch ein wenig umformulieren, indem man "sind" (Verb "sein" in 3. Person Mehrzahl) einfügt.

"Die meisten Lokale in unserer kleinen Stadt sind ja ab Mitternacht geschlossen"

Answer (score -2):

**Sind** wäre hier auch möglich, würde die Bedeutung des Satzes aber ganz verändern.

> Die meisten Lokale in unserer kleinen Stadt **haben** ja ab Mitternacht geschlossen.

Das heißt, die Schließungen sind in der Vergangenheit passiert, zum Beispiel gestern Nacht.

> Die meisten Lokale in unserer kleinen Stadt **sind** ja ab Mitternacht geschlossen.

Das heißt, die Schließungen passieren als eine Routine, zum Beispiel jeden Tag.

Du hast Recht, dass es sich in dem Satz um eine Zustandsänderung handelt, aber *schließen* ist nicht eines der Verben, deren Perfektform mit *sein* gebildet wird.

Comment: Die Antwort geht leider haarscharf am entscheidenden Punkt vorbei: _geschlossen haben_ in der Frage ist überhaupt kein Perfekt.

Comment: @chirlu Das sehe ich aber anders. Der Satz befindet sich in [dieser Übung zur Perfektbildung](http://www.unibuc.ro/prof/ratcu_i/docs/2015/mar/03_21_35_11IMG.pdf). Dass es etwas anderes als Perfekt *sein kann*, heißt es nicht, dass es nicht Perfekt *ist* -- zumindest kann man das nicht mit Sicherheit behaupten. Und hier scheint das Perfekt tatsächlich gemeint zu sein.

Comment: Wäre es Perfekt, würde eher _seit_ statt _ab_ stehen.

Comment: Mit *seit* würde ich kein Perfekt benutzen: Die meisten Lokale in unserer kleinen Stadt *sind* ja seit Mitternacht geschlossen.